# Displaying loaded XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created some code that should save and load the canvas object, however when I press the load button the saved canvas isn't loaded. I don't know what I'm doing wrong any help would be greatly appreciated. code below. Thanks.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // button and code to save canvas
    {
        string savedCanvas = XamlWriter.Save(cnv);
        File.WriteAllText("canvas.xaml", savedCanvas);
    }

    void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //button and code for loading canvas
    {
        var savedCanvas = File.ReadAllText("canvas.xaml");
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedCanvas);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        Canvas readerLoadCanvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
    }



    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Block b = new Block();
        hor.Children.Add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "*isn't loaded*" actually mean? Do you get an exception? If not, you probably just want to set `Content = readerLoadCanvas;`

Comment: There isn't an error or exception being showed the loaded contents just weren't being displayed but I'll try   `content =readerloadcanvas;` . Thanks.

Comment: @Clemens that works great I've been trying to figure this out for so long. Thankyou. Would you be able submit that as an answer so I can mark the question as answered thanks. Btw how would I assign the loaded content as a child object of another element?